# Several document.write in iframe in Edge cause SCRIPT70: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-edge

The document.write causing the error SCRIPT70: Permission denied if you use a few document.write inside iframe. This error occurs only in the Edge. In all other browsers this error is not observed.
For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SSP-558</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("1");
    document.write("2");
</script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.width = window.outerWidth;
    iframe.height = window.outerHeight;
    iframe.onload = function () {
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var script = doc.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.text = [
            'document.write("1");',
            'document.write("2");'
        ].join("");

        doc.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will display 12 on the page and in iframe, but it cause an error and displays only 1 inside iframe in Edge.

If you use only one document.write everything works fine. Unfortunately, the code that contains several document.write comes from a third-party developers and they can't change it.

Have you encountered this error and is there any solution for it?

Comment: what happens if you use more writes or totally different js?. If nothing helps, move the iframe content and js to a separate html file and only call that from this script. That should prevent any security errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was found a solution. If you add window in front of document.write the error will not be caused.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SSP-558</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("1");
    document.write("2");
</script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.width = window.outerWidth;
    iframe.height = window.outerHeight;
    iframe.onload = function () {
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var script = doc.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.text = [
            'window.document.write("1");',
            'window.document.write("2");'
        ].join("");

        doc.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the funny thing is the first write does not need a `window.document` it works without that, but all other writes after that need the window part... strange

Comment: Although I was not using an iframe, this also fixed my SCRIPT70: Permission denied when trying to use document.write(''). Added a window.document.write('') in front and it solved the error.